alter user identified by based on a condition
Trying to develop a simple SQL script to change passwords for bunch of users on a fleet of databases using alter user username identified by password;. Some of the users may or may not exist. Thought of writing it as a PL/SQL but that would make it more complex and I did not want to go that route.
There is one condition though that I can use from syscontext that I can check before running that alter statement. Is that possible at all to do something like that?
I am thinking something like alter user ... case when... or something of that sort.
I know this is a long shot and downright stupid also. Thought to ask before assuming things and sound stupid along the way! Appreciate your inputs!
Update 1:
Some additional details.
I have a bash script as follows, annotating it basically:
for dbname in dblist
do
sqlplus user@$dbname <<EOF
alter user bob identified by bob;
alter user jim identified by jim;
EOF
done

I'd like to add a condition for jim's user, run it only if it exists in that given database.
Edit 10/31:
Finally I got this almost done, but looks like the execute immediate is not liking variables. Any ideas are appreciated.
I have given both options username.column_value and :username.column_value at the end using a quoted string.
Appreciate your help fixing this one.
  sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF
  --set verify off echo off feed off head off trimspool off newpage none serverout on linesize 200
  set serverout on
  --spool "$spfile" append
  prompt --################################################################
  prompt $dbname
  prompt --################################################################
  conn sys/$pass@$dbname as sysdba
  set serverout on
  alter session set nls_date_format = 'mm/dd/yyyy/ hh24:mi:ss';
  select username, expiry_date from dba_users where username in ('JIM', 'BOB');
  --
    DECLARE
    users_exists integer;
    BEGIN
      FOR username IN (SELECT column_value FROM table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('JIM','BOB'))) LOOP
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO users_exists FROM dba_users WHERE username = username.column_value;
        --dbms_output.put_line(username.column_value|| ' = '|| users_exists);
        IF (users_exists = 1)
        THEN
          dbms_output.put_line(username.column_value||' User exists');
          --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER USER username.column_value identified by welcome321';
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER USER :text_string identified by welcome321' using 'username.column_value';
        ELSE
          dbms_output.put_line(username.column_value||' User doest not exist');
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
    END;
    /
  --
EOF


Please provide a database schema and describe conditions you want to use in a query so it easier to help create a query.

You haven't said what context value you'd use, or how that would help; and you can't use a case expression inside an alter statement, so it's not really clear what your idea is. This would be a fairly simple PL/SQL loop to execute dynamic SQL only for users that do exist (like this), so what is your objection to using PL/SQL?

Thanks a lot for jumping on it immediately. Updated the question under  Update 1.

Since Oracle 23c, you can use ALTER USER with IF EXISTS:
ALTER USER IF EXISTS …

Description of the ALTER USER

Before Oracle 23c, you can use PL/SQL:
DECLARE
users_exists integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO users_exists FROM dba_users WHERE username='bob';
  IF (users_exists = 1) THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER USER bob …';
  END IF;
END;
/


Thanks a lot. I am going to put this in the bash loop and see how that goes. Thanks for the tip on 23c if condition :)

I was able to get this going, thanks for looking into it:
Snippets of additions here:
DECLARE
users_exists integer;
exec_str varchar2(100);

...
exec_str := 'alter user '|| username.column_value || ' identified by welcome321';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE exec_str;

